# How can I make it so that users can add variables to a class and choose type in C++?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to have a variable be determined by user-picked parameters and weights they choose as sort of a template, but C++ needs to know types at runtime, so what could I do?

Let's say user wants to create a task template with the parameters a of type bool, b of type int, and c of type int with weights x, y, and z respectively.

Im using Qt if its any help.

Comment: `but C++ needs to know types at runtime` Not true, C++ needs to know types at compile time, by runtime all types have been forgotten. That's why you can't access or modify type information at run time.

Comment: You might want to look at the standard library classes `std::any` and `std::variant` that allow you to store different types in a single variable.

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you're trying to do. It's really really **not** a good idea. The problem with your approach is that you're trying to use the mechanisms of C++ as a functionality of your application.

**You can't create new classes at runtime.**

The closest thing you could get to that is a program that **generates the classes code** (text) for the objects that the users create.

Comment: Thanks, then if I wanted to do it anyways should I change languages to one that supports something like this? Or should I just change the approach I'm taking?

Comment: I think there there is a problem with the way you're trying to solve your problem. What are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: I want to let the user choose how stuff is sorted, and the value stuff will be sorted in is a combination of values and weights, and I wanted to see if I could let the user make their own template/class with values and weights of their choosing.